# ElasticBeanStalk not deploying my node app

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Git is setup in apps top level directory, /home/bitnami/genapp, and the app is commited to Git. This is an AWS instance running a Binami AMI for Node. EB is installed in /genapp. I can do an `eb deploy` and I see this:

```
bitnami@ip-10-99-200-73:~/genapp$ eb deploy
Creating application version archive "app-1cff-160323_170817".
Uploading genapp/app-1cff-160323_170817.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
INFO: Environment update is starting.
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).
INFO: New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
INFO: Environment update completed successfully.
```

When I ssh into the EBS (`eb ssh`) instance why don't I see any sign of the deployed app? For instance there is no `/home/bitnami` directory? When I ssh in I'm a user named `ec2-user`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an **EC2** instance running a Bitnami AMI, and not an Elastic Beanstalk environment running the Bitnami AMI (I'm not sure how you'd even do this.) If you want to run node on Elastic Beanstalk with all the auto-deploy goodness, you'll want to use the preconfigured node.js environment.

Comment: Right i am running an EC2 Binami instance, this is my dev environment, which i'm deploying from...when i run the sequence of 'eb' commands on this instance, a new EBS instance gets created. Its this new instance that i expected to see my app running on...but i don't?

Comment: OK, I think there's some confusion here. Elastic Beanstalk (EB) will spin up an instance *using the Amazon Linux AMI*, and *not* the Bitnami AMI. That's why you don't see `/home/bitnami`; you're SSHing in to the EB instance and not the EC2.

Comment: Yes most definite confusion points! 1] When i did the 'eb init' i got a prompt asking 'It appears you are using Node.js. Is this correct?', and i anwsered 'y'...so i'm thinking EB is smart enough to spin up an EB instance running Node. 2] According to the AWS docs I've read, if you run the 'eb deploy' in a directory  that has been commited to Github, it will deploy that Git app to the EB instance that it spins up...

Comment: From AWS docs:When you run eb deploy, the EB CLI bundles up the contents of your project directory and deploys it to your environment.

Note
If you have initialized a git repository in your project folder, the EB CLI will always deploy the latest commit, even if you have pending changes. Commit your changes prior to running eb deploy to deploy them to your environment.

Comment: Yup! If all went well, this new EC2 instance is running your node app right now. The Amazon AMI is a little different though. You can check node.js logs at `/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log`. Your actual app lives at `/var/app/current/`

Comment: Wow...it is there! Dude you rock!! But this EB instance does not have Node and npm installed. So I can't run the app. Is it possible to configure EBS to spin-up a Bitnami Node.js instance instead of a vanilla aWS linux instance?

Comment: While you technically *could* use a Bitnami AMI, I'm not sure it would be worth the trouble to get it to working with all the EB goodness. The EB instance does have node "installed", it's just not in your path. In fact, there should be 5 different versions of node under `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install`. :) EB instances aren't really meant to be SSHed in to. EB is meant to be handed code, and do magic. When you launched the instance, it *tried* to run your node app. If it's not doing what you expected, try running the command `eb logs` from your git repo.

Comment: Ok thanks again Tanner. This is turning out to be not as simple as AWS makes it out to be. Sooooo...I'm going to finish building my API on my Bitnami Node EC2. If what I'm building turns out to be sucessful...I'll worry about scaling to EBS at that time. Thanks again!...and corsets...really?!

Comment: Weird, right? :) Who knew people still bought those things. The site is running as a node.js app on Elastic Beanstalk right now actually.